# Generic SQL parameters not working in an SqlDataSource for a MySQL connector in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I installed mysql-connector-net-6.4.4.msi to gain access to mySql from vs2010.

When I bind a control to an SqlDataSource and run an SQL such as

```
select case when r.id is null then 'Not Scanned' else 'Scanned' end as status, 
    count(*) as count
from scanned_items as s
left join required_items as r 
    on s.barcode = r.barcode and s.fk_load_id = r.fk_load_id
where s.fk_load_id = @LoadId
group by 1
```

It displays an error "There was an error executing the query.  Please check the syntax of the command and if present, the types and values of the parameters and ensure they are correct." when I test the SQL query from the designer.

This is because I am using the @LoadId parameter, I tired using ? instead but I get the same error.  I was using DB2 earlier and it always asked me for the value to use for the paremeter before executing the query.

How do I fix this?

Comment: That's the way to execute the query from code, once you have declared the parameter and its value... But I have never done something like that from the DB console

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge  Connector/bind can't ask! they does not have a UI for that.
Keep your sql as it is and do a

> yourSQLstatement.replace("@LoadId",YourValue)

before executing the select.